# Android 7 Network Unreachable

Tags: android, sockets, networking, network-programming, android-networking

Through my app, 2 devices can connect by a normal `socket` connection.

It is working on every device that i have tested, but on devices that have Android 7 it doesn't work, it gives me `Network unreachable` on the creation of the socket. I did some research and I could not find the solution or even behavourial changes on the devices with Nougat.

**Does any of you know a possible solution ?**

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?